# Minix 3 TTY incoming character to int

Tags: c, minix

Please refer to the following code snippet, I will be referring to the line numbers on it:

https://gist.github.com/wilbertcr/474c6a13e377dc8ce51a

As you can see on line 172-200, I created a modified version of the original back_over function, which just moves the pointer without erasing the character that's moving over.

Outside of the function in_process, and as a global variable, I created int verase, see line 1, which I use on line 82 to indicate CTRL+H has been pressed(ch == tp->tty_termios.c_cc[VERASED]).

My idea is to use this  as a flag so I can catch the next character, which should be the number of spaces I need to back_over, and do that by calling back_over the number of times indicated by that next character.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to turn that next character into its corresponding int so that I can use it on the for loop. Lines 27-38 show a failed attempt to do that, however, no matter how small the key I press(I've tried 1 and 2 and 3), it always takes me to the beginning of the line(luckily back_over doesn't go beyond a line break--see line 185).

It seems like the for loop is being executed more than the it should, which I suspect is happening because "number" is not really 1 or 2 or 3 but something else, something the for loop is interpreting as much bigger than the number I am pressing in the keyboard. I would appreciate some help on how can I turn it into an int.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was just a matter of doing:

`ch=ch-'0'`